# Remove the last grouping separator when using DecimalFormat Grouping java

Tags: java, android, formatting, string-formatting, decimalformat

I want to format lengthy double numbers in my android calculator app 
2 problems ...
First is that I want to enable Grouping by 3 so 1200 would be shown 1,200
. But for numbers like 1000 what I get is 1, 
 
How can I get 1,000 for result ?

also another problem is that  I want Results with up to 25 integer digits and 4 decimal fraction digits ... but even though I set Decimalformat maximum to 25, after number of integers surpasses 18,  Digits turn to be zeros. for example what I want is 
1,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111 
but I get 
1,111,111,111,111,111,110,000,000, 
Here's the code

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(25);
    df.setGroupingUsed(true);
    df.setGroupingSize(3);
    String formatted = df.format(mResultBeforeFormatting);
```

what pattern should I use ?

Comment: The first part is right in adding the commas. Why don't you then split it into an array by `,`?

Comment: that's not clean coding !
thousand lines of code have been written in java classes so that I don't custom code for these stuff

Answer (score 2):

Ok so for others who face this problem like me 
for first part best pattern was

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.####");
```

for second problem as "x-code" noted it apears there's no hope using double . should try using BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

I found answers to both parts of the question right here on StackOverflow.

> First is that I want to enable Grouping by 3

[Here are several solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253121/android-split-by) to the grouping problem.

> another problem is that I want Results with up to 25 integer digits

In this case what's really happening is that [Java doubles can't represent 25 decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java).

For this problem you might want to look at the BigDecimal class, which can represent the numbers in your example.

Comment: Well for grouping actually those answers either don't address this problem or don't use native java classes (custom code)
With BigDecimal I think your'e right